# ASP.NET Core 2.2 How to bind domain names while supporting HTTPS PFX certificates ？

Tags: asp.net-core, https, .net-core, pfx

In ASP.NET Core 2.2, how do I bind domain names while supporting HTTPS PFX certificates ？

Program.cs

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseUrls("https://api.06ko.com:5151")
        .UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5151, listenOptions =>
            {
                listenOptions.UseHttps("server.pfx", "957qk3z3j163gwr");
            });
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Run:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
  Overriding address(es) 'https://api.06ko.com:5151'. Binding to endpoints defined in UseKestrel() instead.
```

Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\Users\joey\source\repos\Scorpio\src\Scorpio.DataCenter.API\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\publish
Now listening on: https://127.0.0.1:5151
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Comment: Just call it with the domain directly: `options.Listen("api.06ko.com", 5151, listenOptions => …)`

Comment: Thank you. I finally realized this.   .UseKestrel(option => {
               option.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5151, listenOptions => {
                   listenOptions.UseHttps("api.xxxxx.com.pfx", "password");
               });
           })